# How to install gcc-5.5.0 in raspberry pi 4B-64bit

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, compiler-errors, pi

I have a project that requires a low version of the `gcc` compiler to be installed on the Raspberry PI, and I have tried two approaches, neither of which has worked.

I tried two approaches.

The first option is to install `gcc` directly with `apt`, but the `5.5.0` version is not supported, so it is abandoned.
Second, download `gcc-5.5.0` source code to try to compile and install, the error is as follows, I can't solve it.

[image]

Additional information: Raspberry PI uses the latest official system, `gcc` version `12.2`.

Comment: Have you considered fixing your code so that it works with a newer version of the compiler?  Most reasonably standard C code should compile with any version of the compiler.

Comment: Sorry. This code is the source code of the gcc compiler, and it doesn't seem like I have the power to change it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: (1) No gcc errors are visible in the screenshot (2) Screenshots of errors are in general useless and should not be posted here, post text as text (3) You are trying to compile gcc-5. What do you plan to compile *with* gcc-5 that you cannot compile with a modern release?

Comment: (1) (2)... /.. /./gcc/reload1.c:115:24: error:  use of an operand of type 'bool' in 'operator++' is forbidden in C++17           This is one of the errors. The problem seems to be that the code version of gcc5.5.0 is too low for gcc12 to compile. The solution of the problem is stuck in a loop.
(3) I'm going to compile and install opencv-3.4.15 on Raspberry PI, which is also an older version.

Comment: Can't you use just docker with really old debian/ubuntu and install gcc 5.5.0 here?

Answer (score 0):

How do you build image for your device ?

If you build by yocto, you can build **SDK** with it and install into your device

```
bitbake core-weston-minimal -c populate_sdk
```

Or install on your Host PC and compile source then scp output to your device